# CSS Div Footer When Resize The Browser

Tags: css, html, footer

I working on a page with a footer. The footer's positioning is like it should, but I have an problem when i resize the browser from bottom to top. For details, you can see the image below :

[image]

Here it's my css footer code :

```
.footer_page {
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
bottom: 30px;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

Someone have an suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the footer doesn't stay fixed to the bottom, try

```
.footer_page, .push {
  clear: both;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 30px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

so adding `.push` and `clear:both`.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom 30px signifies bottom of the window. Calculate the distance from top you need your footer to have and give 
`top:500px`

A better way is to give a large `div id="page"` around your entire page with required height, say 1000 px, and then footer with bottom 30px.

```
#page{position:absolute;height:1000px}
#page #footer{position:absolute;bottom:30px}
```

If this seems too much or height of page is variable, let footer be **part of flow of the document**.In such cases it is better not to use absolute positioning.

You can also do this with some javascript magic.

What I am saying is, suppose total height of your page is 1000px. Put a wrapper around entire page with id page, give absolute positioning and height 1000px, then put footer in the end.

Comment: Uhh footers are meant to be at the bottom of the page. People have different screen resolutions and sizes so you can'n let the footer be an x amount of pixels from the top. That might result in having your footer in the middle of the screen...

Comment: Nope, hardly, put it at end of page, that's more important. One must calculate distance from top properly, and I guess the height of page matters too, not just height of the screen.

Comment: Of course, i was assuming that he didn't want scrollbars, because that seems to be the problem. When you don't want scrollbars, it's almost impossible to use absolute positioning.

Comment: If he doesnt want scroll bars, hes using liquid display layout. how about setting page height to 100% and over flow hidden??? and some javascript to decide some styles based on screen height and innerheight?? Anyways, why are we discussing??? Wheres he???